# How to use Array.prototype.some() with an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to do the following:

```
command.permissions.some(async permissionsKey => {
        switch (permissionsKey) {
            case "all": {
                return true;
            }
            case "OWNER": {
                return await msg.roomContext.isRoomOwnerId(msg.getStaticUserUID());
            }
            default: {
                return config.users_groups[permissionsKey].includes(msg.getStaticUserUID());
            }
        }
    });
```

However it always is true because Array.prototype.some does not expect an async function so a promise is returned when the function is called. A Promise is truthy.

I was wondering the best away to use an async function with any of the  Array.prototype functions, specifically the some function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the result as soon as the first promise resolves with `true`, you can do that too:

```
const somePromise = promises =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (promises.length === 0) {
            resolve(false);
            return;
        }

        let resolveCount = 0;
        const resolved = value => {
            if (value) {
                resolve(true);
            } else if (++resolveCount === promises.length) {
                resolve(false);
            }
        };

        for (const promise of promises) {
            promise.then(resolved, reject);
        }
    });
```

Alternative fancy approach:

```
const never = new Promise(() => {});

const somePromise = promises => Promise.race([
    Promise.race(promises.map(async p => !!await p || never)),
    Promise.all(promises).then(r => r.some(Boolean)),
]);
```

In your specific case, though, since there’s at most one promise, there’s a much better way to do it:

```
let hasPermission =
    command.permissions.some(permissionsKey => {
        switch (permissionsKey) {
            case "all":
                return true;
            case "OWNER":
                return false;
            default:
                return config.users_groups[permissionsKey].includes(msg.getStaticUserUID());
        }
    });

if (!hasPermission && command.permissions.includes("OWNER")) {
    hasPermission = await msg.roomContext.isRoomOwnerId(msg.getStaticUserUID());
}
```

Comment: `resolve` in the `resolved` function doesn't stop execution of the parent promise. Although it resolved properly, won't the rest of the promises run anyway?

Comment: @JBis: You can’t stop execution of a promise. It’s actually not the promise itself that executes; a promise just holds either pending + what to do when fulfilled, resolved + a value, or rejected + an error. Some promise libraries extend this with cancellation mechanisms, but ES promises don’t have that, and there’s no way to detach the `.then` actions from the other promises either, for example. (Compare `Promise.race`.)

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL9sark6/). Every promise is ran even though not all need to be. Maybe I am implementing the function incorrectly? That was the issue with the below answer, the only difference here is that it will resolve faster, right?

Comment: @JBis: Sure, you know not all of the tasks (not promises – when getting into the details like this, it’s again helpful to remember that promises don’t run) don’t need to run as long as you get a `true`. But ahead of time, you don’t know which, so you have to start them all anyway. Once started, there’s no mechanism to stop them. If your calls are expensive and *can* be stopped, then an improvement would be to stop them, yes.

Comment: @JBis: Or, if you want to go through one at a time – in serial instead of in parallel – CertainPerformance’s example with the `await fn()` inside the loop is what you need.

Comment: So its efficiency or speed, you can't get both. Ok thanks.

Comment: `somePromise` does not handle an empty input array properly

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for a similar use, then found this great article presenting this manual asyncSome function:
https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-some-and-every-in-javascript/

It will also break the loop when a predicate returns a truthy value:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const asyncSome = async (arr, predicate) => {
    for (let e of arr) {
        if (await predicate(e)) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

// Example of use for this function:
const res = await asyncSome(arr, async (i) => {
    console.log(`Checking ${i}`);
    await sleep(10);
    return i % 2 === 0;
});
```

---

Applied to this use case it would simply be:

```js
asyncSome(command.permissions, async permissionsKey => {
        switch (permissionsKey) {
            case "all": {
                return true;
            }
            case "OWNER": {
                return await msg.roomContext.isRoomOwnerId(msg.getStaticUserUID());
            }
            default: {
                return config.users_groups[permissionsKey].includes(msg.getStaticUserUID());
            }
        }
    });
```

It's as simple as the OP's suggested way.

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap it with `map` function, like this (I'm using typescript to clarify the code but you can easily convert it to javascript):

```
 let list: any[] = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];

 async function validator(someObject: any): Promise<boolean> {

     await // do some async work and 
     return // boolean expression

 }

 let someResult = (await Promise.all(list.map(validator))).some(b => b);
```

although you are "looping" over the array 2 times (in the worst case), the complexity still remains O(n).

P.S. the same works for `every` function

Comment: Your question should be the correct one. Elegant one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Transform the array into an array of Promises first, then call `Promise.all` on it, and check whether `.some` of the results array are truthy. You can avoid waiting for the whole array of Promises to resolve by checking whether `.some` of the items in the Promise array are truthy non-Promises, if you want:

```
cpermisPromises = command.permissions.map(permissionsKey => {
  switch (permissionsKey) {
    case "all":
      {
        return true;
      }
    case "OWNER":
      {
        return msg.roomContext.isRoomOwnerId(msg.getStaticUserUID());
      }
    default:
      {
        return config.users_groups[permissionsKey].includes(msg.getStaticUserUID());
      }
  }
});
if (cpermisPromises.some(result => result && typeof result.then !== 'function')) {
  // at least one was truthy, don't need to wait for async call to complete
} else {
  Promise.all(cpermisPromises).then((results) => {
    if (results.some(result => result)) {
      // at least one was truthy
    }
  });
}
```

`Promise.all` can accept arrays containing *any* values, but will wait for all Promise values to resolve before the `Promise.all` resolves.

Here's an alternative which allows you to check whether any of the synchronous values are truthy before running the Promises:

```
let found = false;
const promFns = [];
forloop:
for (let i = 0; i < command.permissions.length; i++) {
  const permissionsKey = command.permissions[i];
  switch (permissionsKey) {
    case "all":
      found = true;
      break forloop;
    case "OWNER":
      proms.push(() => msg.roomContext.isRoomOwnerId(msg.getStaticUserUID()));
      break;
    default:
      if (config.users_groups[permissionsKey].includes(msg.getStaticUserUID())) {
        found = true;
        break forloop;
      }
  }
}
if (found) {
  // done, at least one truthy value was found synchronously
} else {
  // need to run promises
  Promise.all(
    promFns.map(fn => fn())
  )
    .then((results) => {
      if (results.some(result => result)) {
        // done, at least one truthy value was found asynchronously
      } else {
        // no truthy value was found
      }
    });
}
```

Or, if want to send out requests serially, which might lead to fewer requests overall, but will take longer to complete, replace the `Promise.all` with:

```
let foundProm = false;
for (const fn of promFns) {
  if (await fn()) {
    foundProm = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (foundProm) {
  // done, at least one truthy value was found synchronously
}else {
  // no truthy value was found
}
```

Comment: While this will work, it doesn't halt early if one of the promises resolves true, which defeats the purposes the benefit of using the some function in the first place.