# Array.prototype.some() asynchronous

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await

I need to run an asynchronous code inside an `array.some()` which in itself is inside and `array.every()`.
So basically I wanted the callbacks to be `async` so I can use `await` inside them.

But neither `Array.prototype.some()` nor `Array.prototype.every()` accept asynchronous callbacks, which would require them to return a Promise instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553286/how-to-use-array-prototype-some-with-an-async-function/56553349#56553349 has a `some` with a few more optimizations, but this is probably a better question for it since that question was better solved in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

This are the asynchronous versions of `some()` and `every()` that I came up with

#### someAsync()

```js
Array.prototype.someAsync = function (callbackfn) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        await Promise.all(this.map(async item => {
            if (await callbackfn(item))   resolve(true)
        })).catch(reject)
        resolve(false)
    })
}

// Examples
['',0,undefined,false].someAsync(async e=>e).then(e=>console.log(e)) // false
['',0,undefined,false,true].someAsync(async e=>e).then(e=>console.log(e)) // true
```

#### everyAsync()

```js
Array.prototype.everyAsync = function (callbackfn) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        await Promise.all(this.map(async item => {
            if (! await callbackfn(item))   resolve(false)
        })).catch(reject)
        resolve(true)
    })
}

// Examples
[[],{},1,true].everyAsync(async e=>e).then(e=>console.log(e)) // true
[[],{},1,true,false].everyAsync(async e=>e).then(e=>console.log(e)) // false
```

### Disadvantages

- They only accept the callback and with one argument only
- Even though `someAsync()` resolves `true` as soon as a *truthy* value is resolved and `everyAsync()` resolves `false` as soon as a *falsy* value is resolved, the callback is still executed till the end for **every** element, even if the method's promise has already resolved. I think this has no straightforward solution as long as [promises are not cancellable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise)

Comment: Promise executors shouldn’t be `async` when the they can throw, and these ones can – any rejections in the array will end up making an unhandled rejection. `(resolve, reject) => Promise.all(…).then(() => { resolve(false or true) }).catch(reject)` instead, maybe?

Comment: The disadvantage only exists because the elements are not processed sequentially. Processing the elements sequentially has it's own disadvantages, but it is more in line with the synchronous version of these methods.

Comment: @Ry- why not? You just have to remember to use `try/catch` and call `reject` in the catch block. Similar to your proposal using `then/catch`.

Comment: Made this a wiki, so you can all improve it

Comment: @JakeHolzinger: I said (well, typoed with an extra “the”) “when they can throw”. If you use `try` correctly, they can’t throw.